# Как установить заголовок HTTP_X_REAL_IP в xampp

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp, php

На продуктиве  апач стоит за nginx, а мой локальный на XAMPP. Как смоделировать такойже ответ как на продуктиве на моем локальном, а иммено, переменную сервера HTTP_X_REAL_IP, каторой на локале нету?

Comment: Разрабатывать/тестировать лучше в таком-же окружении в каком оно будет работать в боевых условиях. Развернуть вебсервер в какой-то виртуалке например не особо сложно.

Ну или как вариант добавить к xampp nginx

Answer (score 1):

Разверни маленькую виртуалочку с линуксом, пользуясь системой автоматизации [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) c уже готовыми [настроенными образами](https://vagrantcloud.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&provider=&q=nginx+php+debian)